# Python - How to get port of sender socket (UDP)

Tags: python, sockets, udp

If I have a UDP socket like so:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

and the socket can send data:

```
sock.sendto("message", address)
```

How do I find out the port of the socket - the port used when sending data to `address`?

**EDIT:** I tried `sock.getsockname()` but this raises an error: `[Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the python socket class, but based on what I've read here https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getnameinfo
perhaps
`socket.getnameinfo()[1]` might work

since .getsockname() returns a 2-tuple (host, port)

The socket must be bound before you can use `.getsockname()` by doing `sock.bind(('', 0))`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you'd just actually use `.getsockname` to get the tuple countaining host,port that the socket is bound to.

Comment: Alright. I've amended accordingly. Thanks for the information!

Comment: `.getsockname()` raises an error though, probably because I am not binding it to a port but instead I am letting it find a port itself for me.

Comment: ah, I see. Then you need to bind it to port 0 first, and then you should be able to use getsockname

Comment: @MarcusMüller I will try that now

Comment: @MarcusMüller Perfect, that seems to work, thank you!

Comment: can you, or @JoelLee himself, amend the answer to reflect this success, please? We need something that you can accept :)